# Connection pool is full warning while reading S3 objects via multiple threads

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3

I am using boto3 to read s3 objects

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3', region_name='us-east-1')
obj = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=S3_BUCKET, Key=key)
```

I am running this via 50-100 threads to access different objects and getting warning :

> urllib3.connectionpool - WARNING - Connection pool is full, discarding connection: s3.amazonaws.com

How can I increase the connection pool size?

Is there any better way to access different S3 objects with multiple threads?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding `max_pool_connections` (default 10) solved it.

```
client_config = botocore.config.Config(
    max_pool_connections=50
)
s3_client = boto3.client('s3', region_name='us-east-1', config=client_config)
```

Comment: Is there a way to use this when initializing s3 using `aws_session.resource('s3')`?

Comment: resource api equivalent: ```s3_resource = boto3.Session().resource("s3", config=botocore.config.Config(max_pool_connections=50))```

Answer (score 0):

For those using awswrangler, you can pass the argument as follows:

```
wr.config.botocore_config = botocore.config.Config(
  retries={"max_attempts": 10}, 
  connect_timeout=20, 
  max_pool_connections=30)
```